# PHP TCPDF Output does not work, Cant Download PDF, No Errors are displayed

Tags: php, pdf, output, tcpdf

The Output in TCPDF doesnt work in my Code. There are also no Errors?

```
$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'D');
```

The Only Parameter that seems to work is 'F' (It allows the generated pdf to be saved as a local file.)

I want the PDF to be downloadable.

I have already tried to put `ob_end_clean();` before output and give the absolute path of the pdf, but still no success.

EDIT:
Here is my Code (its basically the TCPDF Example 001):

```
//PDF Test POC
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Superadmin');
$pdf->SetTitle('Licenses');
$pdf->SetSubject('Licenses Report');
$pdf->SetKeywords('App, PDF, example, license, list');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, "Title", "Stringus", array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();

// set text shadow effect
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

// Set some content to print
$html = <<<EOD
<h1>Welcome to <a href="http://www.tcpdf.org" style="text-decoration:none;background-color:#CC0000;color:black;">&nbsp;<span style="color:black;">TC</span><span style="color:white;">PDF</span>&nbsp;</a>!</h1>
<i>This is the first example of TCPDF library.</i>
<p>This text is printed using the <i>writeHTMLCell()</i> method but you can also use: <i>Multicell(), writeHTML(), Write(), Cell() and Text()</i>.</p>
<p>Please check the source code documentation and other examples for further information.</p>
<p style="color:#CC0000;">TO IMPROVE AND EXPAND TCPDF I NEED YOUR SUPPORT, PLEASE <a href="http://sourceforge.net/donate/index.php?group_id=128076">MAKE A DONATION!</a></p>
EOD;

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'D');
//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

Comment: What _exactly_ does "doesn't work" mean (what output did you get, and what did you expect to get)? What _exactly_ is the code you're running (what you've shown isn't even valid PHP, let alone a [mre])?

Comment: Isn't saving the PDF to a local file the same as downloading then?

Comment: I get no Output and weirdly no Error. I have looked at dozens of other StackOverflow Posts but havent anyone having the same Problem as me. Looking at the Headers everything seems to be correct (Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/pdf).Saving the PDF as a local File saves it on the Server the Code is running. But i want to have a PDF Download ('D' Parameter).

Comment: Any luck so far getting this sorted? I have what sounds like the same issue, with no results besides you so far on Google. I am talking to my hosting provider now in the hopes of finding a header issue.

Comment: @G4Hu the issue is still not solved :( I just used a workaround and downloaded the locally stored file with readfile().

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue can you explain your work around?